# Is there a way to specify a bootstrap server and schema registry for each topic?

Tags: spring, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I'm experiencing a problem, I have an application in spring boot, this application consumes from one topic and produces in another topic.

the topic that the application consumes is on-premises, the topic that the application produces is on cloud aws.

is there a way to specify a bootstrap server and schema registry for each topic?

my application.properties has the following property:

`spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers=localhost:32202 spring.kafka.properties.schema.registry.url=127.0.0.1:8082`

the problem here is that these properties are for both consumer and producer.
I need to specify a bootstrap server for the consumer, another for the producer.
also specify a schema-registry for the consumer, another for the producer.

I don't know if this way is the best way to deal with this problem.
`spring.kafka.consumer.bootstrap-servers=consumer-localhost:32202 spring.kafka.consumer.schema.registry.url=consumer-127.0.0.1:8082 spring.kafka.producer.bootstrap-servers=producer-localhost:10010 spring.kafka.producer.schema.registry.url=producer-127.0.0.1:9090`

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

See [the Spring Boot documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/messaging.html#messaging.kafka.additional-properties).

> The properties supported by auto configuration are shown in the “Integration Properties” section of the Appendix. Note that, for the most part, these properties (hyphenated or camelCase) map directly to the Apache Kafka dotted properties. See the Apache Kafka documentation for details.

> The first few of these properties apply to all components (producers, consumers, admins, and streams) but can be specified at the component level if you wish to use different values. Apache Kafka designates properties with an importance of HIGH, MEDIUM, or LOW. Spring Boot auto-configuration supports all HIGH importance properties, some selected MEDIUM and LOW properties, and any properties that do not have a default value.

> Only a subset of the properties supported by Kafka are available directly through the KafkaProperties class. If you wish to configure the producer or consumer with additional properties that are not directly supported, use the following properties:

```
spring.kafka.properties[prop.one]=first
spring.kafka.admin.properties[prop.two]=second
spring.kafka.consumer.properties[prop.three]=third
spring.kafka.producer.properties[prop.four]=fourth
spring.kafka.streams.properties[prop.five]=fifth
```

So...

```
spring.kafka.consumer.bootstrap-servers=consumer-localhost:32202
spring.kafka.consumer.properties.schema.registry.url=consumer-127.0.0.1:8082
spring.kafka.producer.bootstrap-servers=producer-localhost:10010
spring.kafka.producer.properties.schema.registry.url=producer-127.0.0.1:9090
```

> This sets the common prop.one Kafka property to first (applies to producers, consumers and admins), the prop.two admin property to second, the prop.three consumer property to third, the prop.four producer property to fourth and the prop.five streams property to fifth.